# Missing leading 0 on binary conversion

Tags: c#

I recently got an answer to converting an ASCII string to binary....

```
byte[] inVAR = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

textBox2.Text = string.Join("", inVAR.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2)));
```

This just takes text from Box1 and puts the binary equivalent in Box2.

My problem is that the leading 0's on the binary are missing.

For example: "A" gives "1000001" instead of "01000001"

I suppose I could manually append each character with a leading zero, but I am afraid this may break certain characters that should start with a "1" or are already 8 digits.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PadLeft` to append the right number of characters. If you already have 8 characters, that won't do anything. If you have less, it will add 0 to make it 8 characters.

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join("", inVAR.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2)
    .PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

Answer (score 4):

you can just use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string.Join("", inVAR.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

Comment: I think `PadLeft` should be inside the `Select`

Comment: default search results. corrected. And it's such a beautiful language ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, a misunderstood from my side.

Answer (score 3):

You can add leading zeros to each of the bytes in your array:

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join("", inVAR.Select(b =>
    Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

**If you add zeros to the whole resulting string, it could be wrong if one of the individual bytes results in less than 8 characters.**